# self vs "generic typet" T difference when ceating extension

Tags: ios, runtime, protocols, swift-extensions, class-extensions

I run into an interesting behaviour which I don't understand. Here is code that produces this behaviour:

```
import UIKit

protocol UIViewNibLoading {
    static var nibName: String { get }
}

extension UIView : UIViewNibLoading {

    static var nibName: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }

}

extension UIViewNibLoading where Self : UIView {

    static func loadFromNib<T: UIViewNibLoading>() -> T {
        print(T.nibName)
        print(nibName)
        return UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! T
        // CRASH: return UINib(nibName: T.nibName, bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! T
    }

}
```

Here is output from console when this code is executed:

```
UIView
MyCustomViewSubclass
```

When I call then `loadFromNib` method on my custom class. It produces two different behaviours depending on how do I get the `nibName`.

1. T.nibName: This returns string `UIView`
2. nibName: This returns string `MyCustomViewSubclass`

Do you know what is going on here? Why `self` and `T` is not the same object during the runtime? Here is another one interesting thing I've found out. Here is what you can see in debugger when you put breakpoint into `nibName` getter:

T.nibName:
[image: T.nibName]
nibName:
[image: nibName]

This is called as:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == WidgetAddTableViewController.SectionIndexRecent {
        return WidgetAddHeaderView.loadFromNib()
    } else if section == WidgetAddTableViewController.SectionIndexFreeAndPremium {
        return WidgetAddFilterHeaderView.loadFromNib()
    }
    return nil
}
```

Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: How do you call `loadFromNib`? `T` will be decided at that point, not at this point.

Comment: I call this `MyCustomClass.loadFromNib()` in my controller in viewForHeaderInSection method. At that point it produces described behaviour.

Comment: Right but what do you assign that to? That's the important piece from your code. I'm betting it's something like `let view: UIView = MyCustomClass.loadFromNib()`?

Comment: I return it in that delegate method

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            return WidgetAddHeaderView.loadFromNib()
}

Comment: @RobNapier: do you think that if I would do `let header = WidgetAddHeaderView.loadFromNib()` than it wouldn't produce string `UIView` but `WidgetAddHeaderView`? In my case it mean crash of application because it's looking for nonexisting xib.

Comment: That probably won't compile since it won't be able to figure out `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is resolved at runtime. `T` is resolved at compile-time. So at compile time, your code behaves like this:

```
let returnValue: UIView? = WidgetAddHeaderView.loadFromNib()
return returnValue
```

`loadFromNib` is generic over its return type. Given this code, the only valid return type is `UIView`. Again, this is decided *at compile-time*.

`self` on the other hand, is just a variable. It's a ever-so-slightly special-cased variable, but it's really just a variable. It has a run-time value. So `type(of: self)` is evaluated at run-time. And dynamic dispatch is handled at run-time.

The mistake is that you don't really mean to return "some unknown T that conforms to UIViewNibLoading" (which is what you say you return by making the return type generic). What you mean to return is `Self`, the class that the static function is a member of (determined at compile time). So you say so:

```
extension UIViewNibLoading where Self : UIView {

    static func loadFromNib() -> Self {
        print(nibName)
        return UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
            .instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! Self
    }   
}
```

Or you could promise less (since your caller doesn't actually care) and do this:

```
extension UIViewNibLoading where Self : UIView {

    static func loadFromNib() -> UIView {
        print(nibName)
        return UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
            .instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0]
    }
}
```

But there's no reason to make this method generic, and it in fact hurts you as you've seen.

Comment: I'm going to use this method across the whole application, so the caller will care about the type of returned object. Just in that case of `viewForHeaderInSection` I don't care about object's type. I don't want to typecast it all the time, so return type is important.

Comment: What `Self` means in that implementation? I tried to put there `T` instead, but compiler didn't allow it.

Comment: OK; then you mean `Self`.

Comment: `Self` is the type that the static member was called on, determined at compile-time. So in `UIView.f()`, `Self` is `UIView`. In `UIButton.f()`, `Self` becomes `UIButton`. But it's determined at compile-time.

Comment: What `T` meant in my original implementation? I thought that it's the type on which was static function called, but you just told me that it was `Self`.

Comment: No, `T` is a type parameter passed by the caller (like a normal value parameter, but passed at compile time; you calling it `T` is not special, that's just the name you gave it). In your case, since it's the return value, it is inferred to be the type of the thing the caller assigns it to. You're assigning it to something of type `UIView`, so `T == UIView` because that's what the caller says it is. Again, `T` is just the name of the type parameter you chose to create. "T" doesn't mean anything more than "nibName".

Comment: Your function signature does nothing to promise that `T` is anything other than some type that conforms to `UIViewNibLoading`. It is not at all promised to be `Self`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171724/discussion-between-vojta-and-rob-napier).